# Class php modo extends

Tags: php

Como eu poderia imprimir na tela o `cpf` de acordo com meu código?

O código:

```
<?php

class valida {
    protected $cpf;

    public function cpf($cpf) {
        if(is_numeric($cpf) and $cpf > 11) {
            $this->cpf = $cpf;
            return $cpf;
        }
    }

}
class manda extends valida {
    function foo() {
        return $this->cpf;
    }
}

$cpf1 = $_GET['cpf'];

$p1 = new valida;
$p1->cpf($cpf1);

$sis = new manda;
echo $sis->foo();
```

O que estou fazendo errado ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$p1` não tem nada que ver com `$sis`, pois são objetos diferentes, embora tenham hierarquia de classes.

Se você quer o mesmo CPF em `$sis`, deve atribuir por meio de `cpf()`,

```
$sis = new manda;
$sis->cpf($cpf1);
echo $sis->foo();
```

Fica mais claro entender hierarquia de classes se pensarmos que ela serve para economia de código na classe filha,

```
class manda extends valida {
    public function foo($cpf) {
        // Aproveitando a implementação anterior de cpf().
        $cpf = cpf(100000000000 + $cpf);
        return $cpf;
    }
}

$sis = new valida;
echo $sis->foo($cpf1);
```

EDIT: Troque `cpf()` para

```
public function cpf($cpf) {
    if (is_numeric($cpf) && ceil(log10($cpf)) >= 11) {
        this->$cpf = $cpf + 0;
        return this->$cpf;
    }
}
```

Comment: Fiz desta maneira: https://ideone.com/wANBeV . Parece que a função "cpf" não está verificando a condição, ou seja qualquer valor/cpf está sendo aceito. Poderia me ajudar ? Grata :)

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Comment: Faltou um `$this->` quando chama o método `cpf` dentro de `foo` no segundo código. E particularmente não recomendaria tratar CPF como numérico, pois será ignorados zeros à esquerda e, se for necessário exibí-lo, teria que fazer tratamento para preencher com os zeros faltantes. Mais fácil manter como string e fazer `strlen($cpf)`.

Comment: Fiz deste modo e deu tudo certo: https://ideone.com/Ws6Trl . Obrigada e abraços.